# Communications link failure due to underlying exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Tags: java, sql

I've been looking here on SOF for answers, but whatever I do does not work. I have seen questions similar to mine, so please don't comment saying that this has been answered before. As I said earlier, the previous answers I found did not work for me.

Basically I am just messing around with SQL and decided to make a simple program to save all of my 'customers' from my 'store'. Here is the code for Store.java (Main class)

```
import java.util.UUID;

import com.galanjulio.store.customers.Customer;
import com.galanjulio.store.sql.SQL;

public class Store {

public static void main(String[] args){

    System.out.println("============================");

    SQL sql = new SQL();
    sql.checkTable();

    System.out.println("============================");

    Customer c = new Customer();
    c.setName("Tom");
    c.setUniqueId(UUID.randomUUID());
    c.setCredits(0);

    sql.addToDatabase(c);

}
```

And here is my SQL.java class

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import com.galanjulio.store.customers.Customer;

public class SQL {

private Connection con;
private Statement st = null;

private String connectionString = 
"jdbc:mysql://167.114.67.166:3306/store?user=user&password=pass";

public void checkTable(){
    String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customers` (uuid VARCHAR(36), name VARCHAR(15), credits INT);";
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
        st = con.createStatement();
        st.executeUpdate(query);
        System.out.println("Database created successfully...");
     }catch(SQLException se){
        //Handle errors for JDBC
        System.out.println(se.getMessage());
     }catch(Exception e){
        //Handle errors for Class.forName
         e.printStackTrace();
     }finally{
        //finally block used to close resources
        try{
           if(st != null)
              st.close();
        }catch(SQLException se2){
        }// nothing we can do
        try{
           if(con != null)
              con.close();
        }catch(SQLException se){
            System.out.println(se.getMessage());
        }//end finally try
     }//end try
}

public void addToDatabase(Customer c){
    String query = "INSERT INTO `customers` (uuid, name, credits) VALUES (" + c.getUniqueId() + ", " + c.getName() + ", " + c.getCredits() + ");";

    try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
    st = con.createStatement();
    st.executeUpdate(query);
    System.out.println("Added " + c.getName() + " to the database");
 }catch(SQLException se){
    //Handle errors for JDBC
     System.out.println(se.getMessage());
 }catch(Exception e){
    //Handle errors for Class.forName
     System.out.println("Class.forName has thrown an exception!");
 }finally{
    //finally block used to close resources
    try{
       if(st!=null)
          st.close();
    }catch(SQLException se2){
    }// nothing we can do
    try{
       if(con != null)
          con.close();
    }catch(SQLException se){
        System.out.println(se.getMessage());
    }//end finally try
 }//end try
}
```

Here is the error that I am getting

```
Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.net.ConnectException
MESSAGE: Connection refused: connect

STACKTRACE:

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:271)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2771)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.galanjulio.store.sql.SQL.checkTable(SQL.java:26)
    at com.galanjulio.store.Store.main(Store.java:15)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **



Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
============================
Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.net.ConnectException
MESSAGE: Connection refused: connect

STACKTRACE:

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:271)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2771)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.galanjulio.store.sql.SQL.addToDatabase(SQL.java:57)
    at com.galanjulio.store.Store.main(Store.java:24)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **



Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
```

This is my first question asked on SOF, sorry if this is formatted incorrectly.
Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Are you missing the closing bracket `}` in Store.java ? Or did you mess up while posting your code here ?

Comment: `ConnectionRefused` is always a simple answer and has nothing to do with your code. Either MySQL isn't running on that host or it's firewalled. `ConnectionRefused` means it cannot connect to that port at that host.

Comment: Just saw that, messed it up while posting here, sorry about that. My IDE is giving me no errors and I know how to do bracket spacing so no worries about that :) Sorry about that mistake!

Comment: @ChrisThompson I have MySQL & phpMyAdmin installed on that ip (My virtual private machine). Also there's no reason for why it should be firewalled. Got any other suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: @JulioGalan try changing your connection string to `localhost` instead of the IP. `ConnectionRefused` means the machine it tried to connect to actively declined the connection, so somebody is getting in the way for sure ;)

Comment: @ChrisThompson Changed to localhost and I get the exact same error. I will see what else I can do, thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: "localhost" will work *only if mysql is running on your local PC*!  The "connect error" means there is no server listening on that host (167.114.67.166, localhost... whatever) on that port (3306).

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is "firewall".  Either on your side, on your server's side, or both.

One way to check is to see if *any* client can connect from your PC to the remove server.  For example, "telnet SERVERNAME 3306". Or try a mySQL client from your PC.

My second guess, once you've absolutely verified TCP/IP-level connectivity, is mySQL permissions.

Look here:

- http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/allow-mysql-client-connection/
- http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/mysql-connect-to-your-database-remotely
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connecting.html

Note that "grants" can apply to "db resource" + "db user" + "db client host".

Also note that "mySQL Permissions" generally results in a *different* error, not "Connection refused".  So again - check your hostname, check your firewalls, verify network connectivity.

'Hope that helps!